# How to sum up 1 column and set it as a new record (total time of each member per month) in new table

Tags: mysql, time, sum

How does one sum up `czas` column which is `time(H:m)` records from table `raport` and set it as a new record (as total time of each member per month)  in new table's (time) `june` column?

I'm trying something like this, but it doesn't work:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO time (czerwiec) SELECT SUM(czas) FROM raport WHERE data BETWEEN '2012-06-01' AND '2012-06-30'") or die ('{"success":"false"}');
```

Comment: @KL1M7R0И What is the data type of column `czerwiec`?

Comment: czerwiec means 'june' in polish

Answer (score 0):

Try this SELECT query -

```
SELECT
  SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(czas))) time_sum
FROM
  raport
-- WHERE
--   YEAR(data) = 2012 AND MONTH(data) = 6
GROUP BY
  YEAR(data), MONTH(data)
```

Uncomment WHERE condition to filter dates.

Then use [INSERT...SELECT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html) construction to populate another table.